# How to convert a GridView to an ExpandableListView

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I have used GridView in my project and with that I included the ViewHolder.
Now, the customer wants to show the data using an ExpandableListView for the fact that he wants to only show the header and when the user clicks on the header, it shows the child below it.

- Having no prior experience, I want to know if it possible to change from GridView to ExpandableListView easily in the code.
  Note that I have also included text search on the Grid.  Will that still be available if I switch to ExpandableListView?
- If the above is possible, can anyone help how I could achieve it.

---

The Grid row xml is as follows

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="8dip"
    android:paddingRight="4dip">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.8">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/placeName"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#88FFFFFF"
                android:typeface="sans"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/theme"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/Title"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Details"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scheduleDays"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dip"                
                android:text="Family, Friends, Relatives, Grand-Parents"                
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/rightLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/starButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#00FFFFFF"
                android:src="@drawable/Favourite"/>

 <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/showMeButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                android:src="@drawable/showMe"/>
            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

  <View
    android:id="@+id/separator"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="#33000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

With ListView, I want to show PlaceName, Favourite Button and ShowMe Button as the headers and the rest as the child.

Comment: set `numColumns=1` property in xml

Comment: @rajanks, the numcolumns is already1, however, I need to hide the child data, with numColumns=1, both the header and child data are shown.  I want it to behave exactly as the ExpandableListView.  There is nothing like Header - Child when doing numColumns=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can integrate the Expandable ListView in an Layout, like LinearLayout.
For this Change the Layout type in the layout.xml of your activity

To send the Data to the ListView you need to use an BaseExpandableListAdapter that pulls the Content out of an Array or a Database.

Example for the layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout .... >

  <ExpandableListView
   .... >
  </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you show your xml file. well can be achieve is many ways.

- like change your layout container from grid layout to linear layout

as in your adapter

and set your View in onCreate

```
recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    final LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new Adapter(getActivity());
    recycler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: first you said gird to linear and now you are saying expandable list view.

Comment: The question is How to convert a GridView to an ExpandableListView?